High ram usage in ubuntu
Please help, my Ubuntu when idle uses 5GB of 8GB of RAM, even though I installed Ubuntu because I saw on YouTube that it uses less RAM than Wiindows.

just be grateful you are using what you paid for. Linux uses RAM very efficiently and there is no cause for concern.

you could try the command htop to see which processes are using most of the memory. I wouldn't worry though as it's likely that the system is simply taking advantage of all the memory available to it. Regularly running slowly with 100% memory use is more cause for concern

What tool you use to determine RAM usage? Can you provide sample output?

Unused RAM is wasted RAM....   If your system has available RAM, it usually gets used as CACHE, where it's both used whilst still being available.  Developers have been arguing about whether RAM used as cache should could as USED or not since the late 1970s, as its both being used yet still marked as available, which means tools can use different counts as to used/available RAM which confuses users who've not studied IT (esp. OS theory), so you maybe worrying about nothing.

Good. That means your machine is using the resources efficiently. I don't know what you saw on YouTube (and do remember, YouTube is not a reliable source, it's just some random person who uploaded a video; they could be absolutely correct or entirely wrong), but saying that one operating system uses less RAM than another is meaningless. What you can compare is the minimum RAM the two systems may require. What they use will depend entirely on the what the OSs are currently doing.
Yes, Linux systems, including Ubuntu, can work with less RAM than Windows. That doesn't mean they always use less, it only means that y ou can install and run the system on a machine with less RAM than what is needed by Windows.
Now, the other important thing to remember is that you don't care how much of your RAM is being used. You don't care if it is 90% or 10%. You care about whether the RAM is being used efficiently so your machine is fast and responsive. One of the ways Linux based systems make sure they are fast and responsive is by using as much RAM as possible to ensure that everything is as fast as possible. This is a feature, not a bug.
In addition, Linux has a disk cache which uses RAM to store information from your hard drive, thereby enabling faster access. This means that it looks like your RAM is full, but really, it is still available. Cache files will be dropped as soon as anything else needs to use that RAM. So forget about looking at how much of your RAM appears to be in use: unless your machine feels really slow, you don't care.
Instead, you should look at the amount of RAM available. You can see this in the output of the free command. For example, on my system (which is running Arch, not Ubuntu, but it's the same principle):
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31Gi        16Gi        10Gi       3.0Gi       6.9Gi        14Gi
Swap:           29Gi       9.1Gi        20Gi

So at first glance, it looks like I only have 10G of my 31G free. The truth, however, is that I actually have 14G available to the system. That is the number we are interested in.
Even clearer, this is the output of free on an Ubuntu Server instance I have access to at work:
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251Gi        63Gi        13Gi        18Gi       174Gi       167Gi
Swap:           99Gi        35Gi        64Gi

This looks even scarier. We have 251G RAM and only 13G are marked as "free". Again, that's misleading and the number we really care about is the 167G that are shown as available.
In summary:

Look at RAM available, not RAM used or RAM free values.
You want your RAM to be used, there is no benefit in having it sit there empty.

This is a nice site that explains all this very clearly: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/. Please check it out.

+1 on You want your RAM to be used, there is no benefit in having it sit there empty.

Adding to this, Windows does disk caching too, but it doesn’t list memory used as cache as ‘used’ in almost any place it presents it, so it can often look like it’s using less memory even though it often isn’t.

My opinion is the desktop environment that you use is RAM-consuming. GNOME is slower than other DEs, such as KDE Plasma. Comparison between DE/WMs here

And why are you assuming the OP is using Gnome? Also, your comparison was run on a completely different operating system (BSD), and even there, KDE had higher RAM usage (2843 MB) than Gnome (2622 MB), which has been the case for as long as I can remember, at least 15-20 years now. KDE has always been the heaviest and most feature rich DE.

@terdon KDE 5 in Kubuntu 20.04-24.04 was far lightweight compared to contemporary GNOME versions. KDE 4 was indeed the heaviest DE of its era, but that was more than 10 years ago. I have not tried KDE 6 yet.

@ArchismanPanigrahi yes, but maxhatei2 linked to a reference that showed that KDE was heavier than Gnome so that doesn't support the claim they made. In any case, both KDE and Gnome are behemoths and very heavy. Neither of them can be called lightweight.

The way RAM usage is reported by some tools is... less than helpful.  If you want to understand what is actually using (or not using) RAM, the best tool I can recommend is Mission Center.  The "Memory Composition" graph on the Memory page will give you a better idea of what is actively used by applications, vs what is just e.g. cached data that will automatically be removed if needed.
For what it's worth, if you find yourself running out of RAM (common if you have very little physical RAM and keep lots of applications/browser tabs open), it may be worth buying more RAM, as it's extremely cheap nowadays.
